# Order of words (Oizer U'Moshia) in Shemona Esrei

Tags: words, shemoneh-esrei, nuschaot

In Shemona Esrei in the first Bracha it ends with Melech Oizer U'Moshia U'Magen מלך עוזר ומושיע ומגן, however towards the end of the Bracha of Modim it says HaKail Yeshuasainu V'Ezrasainu Selah האל ישועתנו ועזרתנו סלה. Why does it switch the order and say in one place first Oizer and then Moshia and in the other place it says first Yeshuasainu and then Ezrasainu?

Comment: Why transliterate the English ("HaKail") with a 'K' if you type out the proper word in Hebrew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sefer "Taleley Oros" brings the following explanation from the Bnei Yissaschar: עזרה refers to help even without being requested. ישועה is only after the person asked to be saved. Therefore עזרה is the level of Tzadikim regarding whom it is written (Yishaya 65:24) "Before they call I will answer". In the first three brochos of Shmoneh Esreh we tell the praises of Hashem, and therefore we say עזרה first which is a greater praise - that Hashem helps even before He is called. However, in the brocha of Modim where we thank Hashem for the miracles He does with us, we first thank Him for the ישועה of the majority of the world, because only few Tzadikim merit the עזרה before they ask.